# jquery transformable top and left position

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have two images in a page first image is a large image and second image is a small image placed in a div on big image small image can be drag and drop and rotate to any degree on big image after that i want to save these two images as one image in php

here is live code

http://jsfiddle.net/cQyvG/

but problem is that when i drag small image around i cant get the image position on big image where it is placed

here is my php code
     photoRotation = $_POST["img_angle"];

```
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($sec);
$image_2 = imagerotate($image_2,$photoRotation, -1,0);
$image_1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($first);

imagecopy($image_1, $image_2,$_POST["img_left"],$_POST["img_top"], 0, 0, $_POST["img_width"],$_POST["img_hight"]);
```

this is working but i always get second image on wrong position

jquery.transformable.js
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/jquerytransformablejs

Answer (score 0):

Try getting its [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), not the [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

```
var position = p.offset();
```

Comment: offset get the left from whole page i want only from big image div i mean the relative div